# PreparedStatement and DateTime

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, jodatime

I am trying to use DateTime from the Joda library and I realized that PreparedStatements doesn't support DateTime. What can I do instead? I can set TimeStamp but that's not really what I want. Is there a workaround or do I have to use TimeStamp? In my MySQL database I have also chosen DateTime as the type.

```
      DatabaseConnection dbConnect = new DatabaseConnection();
      PreparedStatement query =dbConnect.getConnect().prepareStatement(sql);

      query.setInt(1, c.getMemberId());
      query.setDateTime(2, c.getStartDate());
      query.setDateTime(3, c.getEndDate());
```

Comment: What's wrong with using TimeStamp? why ins't it appropriate for your usecase?

Comment: I am using DateTime from Joda. Actually I don't even want the time. I only want the date, month and year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setDate(java.sql.Date)` seems like what you're looking for:

```
 query.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(c.getStartDate().getMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `PreparedStatement`, call the `toDate()` method on your `DateTime` objects.

If you are not interested in times, you might as well change your database columns to `DATE`.